# PyTorch single channel conv slower than manual implementation

Tags: pytorch

I want to convolve a 2d matrix with a constant 1d weight kernel in PyTorch. I would have imagined that the fastest way to do this would be to use PyTorch's `conv2d`, but this turns out to be substantially slower than a simple manual implementation. This is, in turn, substantially slower than a simple CUDA version that I wrote (not shown). Is there any way to make the PyTorch version faster? I tried preallocating the output array (the `_out` versions of the implementations, below), but this was even slower. Why does PyTorch not at least automatically use something like my manual implementation for such cases?

The four implementations (`conv2d` and manual, with and without preallocation) are below. I also performed the test after applying JIT to each implementation, but the outcome was the same (manual was fastest).

The output of the code (running on a CPU with PyTorch 1.11.0):

```
True True True
conv 3.8901006870000856
conv_out 4.489796123998531
manual 1.6673853559987037
manual_out 1.976811970002018
jit conv 3.674719169997843
jit conv_out 4.3507045450023725
jit manual 0.31136969999352004
jit manual_out 0.4854257180049899
```

The code:

```py
import torch
import timeit

## Four implementations

def conv(x):
    return torch.nn.functional.conv2d(x, torch.tensor([[[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]]]), padding='valid')

def conv_out(x, out):
    out.copy_(torch.nn.functional.conv2d(x, torch.tensor([[[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]]]), padding='valid'))

def manual(x):
    return 1.0 * x[..., :-2] + 2.0 * x[..., 1:-1] + 3.0 * x[..., 2:]
    
def manual_out(x, out):
    out.copy_(1.0 * x[..., :-2] + 2.0 * x[..., 1:-1] + 3.0 * x[..., 2:])


## Test that all implementations produce the same result

x = torch.arange(256 * 256, dtype=torch.float).reshape(1, 1, 256, 256)
y1 = conv(x)
y2 = torch.empty(1, 1, 256, 254)
conv_out(x, y2)
y3 = manual(x)
y4 = torch.empty(1, 1, 256, 254)
manual_out(x, y4)

print(torch.allclose(y1, y2), torch.allclose(y2, y3), torch.allclose(y3, y4))
    

## Time execution of each implementation

x = torch.arange(256 * 256, dtype=torch.float).reshape(1, 1, 256, 256)
out = torch.empty(1, 1, 256, 254)
n = 10000

print('conv', timeit.timeit(lambda: conv(x), number=n))
print('conv_out', timeit.timeit(lambda: conv_out(x, out), number=n))
print('manual', timeit.timeit(lambda: manual(x), number=n))
print('manual_out', timeit.timeit(lambda: manual_out(x, out), number=n))


## Time execution of each implementation after JIT

conv = torch.jit.script(conv)
conv_out = torch.jit.script(conv_out)
manual = torch.jit.script(manual)
manual_out = torch.jit.script(manual_out)

# Warm-up runs before timing
conv(x)
conv(x)
conv_out(x, out)
conv_out(x, out)
manual(x)
manual(x)
manual_out(x, out)
manual_out(x, out)

print('jit conv', timeit.timeit(lambda: conv(x), number=n))
print('jit conv_out', timeit.timeit(lambda: conv_out(x, out), number=n))
print('jit manual', timeit.timeit(lambda: manual(x), number=n))
print('jit manual_out', timeit.timeit(lambda: manual_out(x, out), number=n))
```

Comment: Mightn't a `torch.nn.conv1D` approach be faster? i.e. for your use case `conv2D` may be overkill

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but `conv1d`, with the matrix rows in the batch dimension, is only slightly faster than `conv2d` and still about ten times slower than my manual approach with JIT.